# Why doesn't docker build copy the files over?

Tags: python, azure, docker, web

I am trying to deploy a python Webapp which is basically an interface for an excel file. The application is based on python.

I've build and ran the container on my local machine and everything is smooth. But when I try to deploy on Azure Web Apps I face an issue which says that my file is missing.

The Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster AS base

WORKDIR /home/mydashboard

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pipenv
COPY Pipfile /home/mydashboard/Pipfile
COPY Pipfile.lock /home/mydashboard/Pipfile.lock
COPY dataset.csv /home/mydashboard/dataset.csv
COPY src/ /home/mydashboard/src
RUN pipenv install --system
WORKDIR /home/mydashboard/src

EXPOSE 8000

CMD gunicorn -b :8000 dashboard_app.main:server
```

Weirdly enough when this runs on the Azure App Service I receive a message which was that "dataset.csv" does not exist.

I printed the files inside of  /home/dashboard/ it seems that it was an empty folder!!

Who does this happen??

It runs perfectly on my personal computer but it seems that it just run on Azure.

Comment: How are you running the container?  In either environment, are you mounting some sort of data volume?

Comment: I do not mount any drive whatsoever. I am running the container on my local Mac device and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

- Your error message is dataset.csv does not exist
- It works on your local machine
- Fails in Azure

Probably dataset.csv exists in the copy from location on your local machine, but is missing in Azure.

Comment: The command ```COPY dataset.csv /home/mydashboard/dataset.csv``` copied the local file into the container image. I've also tried to run the image from a different linux machine and it worked. It's just on Azure App Service that the content is not copied.